# Algolia Hosts unreachable

Tags: laravel-5, algolia

Hello I am using algolia for search on my laravel project. It was working good but now when i search for content it display error. I also tried for composer update, but it is not allowing me to update. i am attaching screenshots of error when i search for content and composer update issue. [Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnUkA.jpg)

[and this as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47g3w.jpg)

Comment: Do you see where it says "Package algolia/algoliasearch-laravel is abandoned" and recommends Laravel Scout? That would probably be a good start. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scout

Comment: yes, i did this. Now the problem is in timeout 1000 miliseconds , if searching takes more than 1000 miliseconds than it shows me error.

Comment: This typically happens when the app id is not correct. Can you check it please? Print what URL you're trying to contact for instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know its an old topic but I'm sharing my experience here. It my help others.

This issue also occurs when ALGOLIA_APP_ID is not properly set up. Usually people use wrong APP ID from algolia dashboard so make sure to use the correct APP ID as shown in the following image.

[image]

Comment: I hope this will other as well

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be taking 1 second to resolve the host, so I recommend you to check your DNS settings or your Internet connection.

But anyway, if you still want to have longer timeouts all you need to do is configure it: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/configuring-timeouts/#methods

Comment: This turned out to be our issue from certain dev systems, though it was due to how busy some dev network interfaces are.  It can especially spring up in the midst of bulk loads via methods like `index.save_objects` which can completely saturate a connection.